# Elasticsearch - Duplicating Types?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I created an index in Elasticsearch, with a type `t1` and documents `doc1`-`docN`. Is there a way, via an API call, to create a new type, `t2`, that contains the same documents as `t1` (`doc1` - `docN`)?

Comment: May I ask what your intention is behind copying the documents to a new type?

Comment: Would Logstash be an option for you?

Comment: According to an [elastic blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) reindexing documents from an old to a new index (although you asked for a type), should be possible directly. Not sure though, if this information is still valid as version 2 braught some changes in the API.

Answer (score 0):

No magic API call for this. You need to index those documents. I suggest this blog post from one of the Elastic developers: http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/05/20/reindex-elasticsearch-with-logstash/

You'd need something around these lines:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "test_index"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
    query => '{"query":{"term":{"_type":{"value":"test_type_1"}}}}'
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@timestamp", "@version" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    port => "9200"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "test_index"
    document_type => "test_type_2"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```